# Symfony querybuilder - Cannot select extra field and OneToMany relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am building a query throw querybuilder objects, something like

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
->select('n, t, ns1m')
->from('App\Entity\Nuclei','n')
->leftJoin('n.statistiche1M', 'ns1m', 'WITH', 'DATE_PART(\'year\', ns1m.dataora) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())')
->leftJoin('n.codicitag', 't')
->where('n.comune = :id_comune')
->setParameter('id_comune', $this->user->getComune()->getId());
```

This query return an array of entity objects "nucleo":

```
array:3 [▼
    0 => App\Entity\Nuclei { ... }
    1 => App\Entity\Nuclei { ... }
    2 => App\Entity\Nuclei { ... }
```

I want to add another column to select

```
->addSelect('SUM(ns1m.totale_peso_conferimenti_indifferenziata) AS total_test')
```

but now the result is:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => App\Entity\Nuclei {#1671 ▶}
    "total_test" => 1520
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▶]
]
```

n.codicitag is a onetomany relations and is a collections of other objects

how can to handle this? Made many tests without success

Answer (score 1):

What is your requested result? Result seems fine. You get sum for every *Nuclei* object.

If you need total sum without changing result structure, create extra query:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('SUM(ns1m.totale_peso_conferimenti_indifferenziata) AS total_test')
    ->from('App\Entity\Statistiche1M','s1m')
    ->where('DATE_PART(\'year\', ns1m.dataora) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())');
```

This query return total sum filtered by current year.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
->select('n, t, ns1m', 'SUM(ns1m.totale_peso_conferimenti_indifferenziata) AS total_test')
->from('App\Entity\Nuclei','n')
->leftJoin('n.statistiche1M', 'ns1m', 'WITH', 'DATE_PART(\'year\', ns1m.dataora) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())')
->leftJoin('n.codicitag', 't')
->where('n.comune = :id_comune')
->setParameter('id_comune', $this->user->getComune()->getId());
```

Because addSelect() create new array.